# How to save matrices from for loop into another matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a *5*-by-*200* matrix where the `i:50:200`, `i=1:50` are related to each other, so for example the matrix columns `1`,`51`,`101`,`151` are related to each other, and columns `49`,`99`,`149`,`199` are also related to each other.

I want to use a `for`-loop to create another matrix that re-sorts the previous matrix based on this relationship.

My code is

```
values=zeros(5,200);

for j=1:50
    for m=1:4:200
        a=factor_mat(:,j:50:200)
        values(:,m)=a
    end
end
```

However, the code does not work.

Comment: `does not work` is not a helpful summary of an issue. Please provide a [minimal, functioning example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an example of inputs/outputs.

Comment: @ AllenLi it looks like you have an indexing issue? can you post the error message as well as what excaza says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening. Let's say we're on the first iteration of the outer loop, so `j == 1`. This effectively gives you:

```
j = 1;
for m=1:4:200
   a=factor_mat(:,j:50:200)
   values(:,m)=a;
end
```

So you're creating the same submatrix for `a` (`j` doesn't change) 50 times and storing it at different places in the `values` matrix. This isn't really what you want to do.

To create each 4-column submatrix once and store them in 50 different places, you need to use `j` to tell you which of the 50 you're currently processing:

```
for j=1:50
   a=factor_mat(:,j:50:200);
   m=j*4;    %// This gives us the **end** of the current range
   values(:,m-3:m)=a;
end
```

I've used a little trick here, because the indices of Matlab arrays start at 1 rather than 0. I've calculated the index of the *last* column we want to insert. For the first group, this is column 4. Since `j == 1`, `j * 4 == 4`. Then I subtract 3 to find the first column index.

---

That will fix the problem you have with your loops. But loops aren't very Matlab-ish. They used to be very slow; now they're adequate. But they're still not the cool way to do things.

To do this without loops, you can use `reshape` and `permute`:

```
a=reshape(factor_mat,[],50,4);
b=permute(a,[1,3,2]);
values=reshape(b,[],200);
```